# Including custom post types in category loop - Walker Nav error

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am using a code snippet to include posts from a custom post type of "videos" within the category results in WordPress.

The code is:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
    if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
        $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
        if($post_type)
            $post_type = $post_type;
        else
            $post_type = array('post','videos');
        $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

This code does work, in terms of returning the correct results. However, it weirdly makes the site menu not work. On investigation, I am getting the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$db_id in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php on line 136

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 126

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 164

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 547

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php on line 550

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$title in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 204

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in /homepages/16/d673645047/htdocs/SiteName/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php on line 204
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I have tested, it is the above code snippet that's the problem. I have seen reports online of this being a known issue but have been unable to find a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the specifics of your problem are, but my approach to querying custom post types is slightly different.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' =>  'testimonials_list', 'order'   => 'ASC'  ); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );    
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> //Do Something <?php endforeach;?>
```